# group_by and summarise dropping values with no error

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am using group_by and summarise to compute the sum of a column by a location variable in another column. The dataframe is formatted as follows:

```
Store  Sales
AB12   12
BD43   32
DC65   65
AB12   1
DC65   3
DC65   4
```

```
store_total <- store %>%
group_by(store) %>%
summarise(total_sales = sum(total_sales))
```

When I run this code, I get the results for AB12 and the rest are NA values. Is there something wrong with the code or should I be using a different function?

Comment: Your example has Store and Sales but your code has store and total_sales. What should we assume is literally what you're using?

Comment: BTW, it's best practice to include reproducible data which others can load to get verbatim what you have, including data formats. The easiest way to do that is by including the output of `dput(store)` in the text of your question. Then we can see whether your actual data is stored as double, integer, character, factor, any grouping, etc. And more important, we can test out a solution and see if it works on your exact data without guessing any of that.

Answer (score 0):

I use Microsoft R Open v 4.0

Take a look at my answer:

Loading library:

```
library(dplyr)
```

Reproducing your dataframe:

```
store = c("AB12",   12,
"BD43",   32,
"DC65",   65,
"AB12",   1,
"DC65",   3,
"DC65",   4)

store<-as.data.frame(matrix(store, ncol=2, byrow=T))
names(store)<-c("Store",  "Sales")
store$Store<-as.factor(store$Store)
store$Sales<-as.numeric(store$Sales)
store


> store
  Store Sales
1  AB12    12
2  BD43    32
3  DC65    65
4  AB12     1
5  DC65     3
6  DC65     4
```

Fixing group_by parameter (`Store` instead of `store`) and summarise (`Sales` instead of `total_sales`)

```
store_total <- store %>%
    group_by(Store) %>%
    summarise(total_sales = sum(Sales))
```

To be honest I don't like tibbles that's why I go back to a normal dataframe.

This is the final result:

```
store_total <- as.data.frame(store_total)
store_total

> store_total
  Store total_sales
1  AB12          13
2  BD43          32
3  DC65          72
```